# How to know which hardware causing this error?

Tags: linux, hardware

I got this today:

```
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  </TASK>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xd5/0xdb
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  start_secondary+0x12a/0x180
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  do_idle+0x83/0xf0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpuidle_idle_call+0x13f/0x1d0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? tick_nohz_stop_tick+0x167/0x1e0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x630
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 00007c49600132ec
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 071c71c71c71c71c R12: ffffffff946f5ec0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RBP: ffffb2000021fe78 R08: 00007c49600132ec R09: 0000000000023140
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RAX: ffff8954beff0f40 RBX: ffff89361beb3400 RCX: 000000000000001f
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb2000021fe28 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Code: ff e8 78 20 6a ff 80 7d d0 00 74 17 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 f6 c4 02 0f 85 3d 03 00 00 31 ff e8 9b 06 72 ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 74 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 12 04 00 00
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xec/0x630
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x12/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  <TASK>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  </IRQ>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7d/0x90
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  irq_exit_rcu+0xe/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __irq_exit_rcu+0x89/0xb0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x12b/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x316
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? clockevents_program_event+0xaa/0x120
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? lapic_next_event+0x20/0x30
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? native_x2apic_icr_read+0x20/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x46/0xc0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __run_timers.part.0+0x1d6/0x280
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? dequeue_skb+0x510/0x510
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  call_timer_fn+0x2c/0x150
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? dequeue_skb+0x510/0x510
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  <IRQ>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Call Trace:
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CR2: 00007f162f172f5f CR3: 000000017a530000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8954befc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R13: ffff89362c94c41c R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R10: 2065756575712074 R11: 696d736e61727420 R12: ffff89362c94c000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RBP: ffffb20000710e98 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffe09e8
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RDX: ffff8954befec6c0 RSI: ffff8954befe0580 RDI: 0000000000000300
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff89362c94c4c8 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb20000710e70 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Code: ff e9 31 ff ff ff 4c 89 e7 c6 05 f5 74 6c 01 01 e8 76 63 f9 ff 44 89 f1 4c 89 e6 48 c7 c7 20 dc cd 93 48 89 c2 e8 87 0e 1a 00 <0f> 0b e9 22 ff ff ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x20f/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./B550 Phantom Gaming 4, BIOS P2.10 08/02/2021
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CPU: 23 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/23 Tainted: P           OE     5.17.5-76051705-generic #202204271406~1655476786~22.04~62dd706
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  videobuf2_common brcmutil cec snd_seq_device ecdh_generic ecc rc_core snd_timer videodev edac_mce_amd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea apple_mfi_fastcharge input_leds joydev mc rapl cfg80211 sysfillrect wmi_bmof sn>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Modules linked in: snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libcurve25519_generic libchacha ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel xt_nat veth tls nf_co>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 23 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:529 dev_watchdog+0x20f/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp7s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

also this:

```
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  </TASK>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xd5/0xdb
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  start_secondary+0x12a/0x180
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  do_idle+0x83/0xf0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpuidle_idle_call+0x13f/0x1d0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? tick_nohz_stop_tick+0x167/0x1e0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xc8/0x630
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 00007c49600132ec
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 071c71c71c71c71c R12: ffffffff946f5ec0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RBP: ffffb2000021fe78 R08: 00007c49600132ec R09: 0000000000023140
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RAX: ffff8954beff0f40 RBX: ffff89361beb3400 RCX: 000000000000001f
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb2000021fe28 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Code: ff e8 78 20 6a ff 80 7d d0 00 74 17 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 f6 c4 02 0f 85 3d 03 00 00 31 ff e8 9b 06 72 ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 f6 0f 88 74 01 00 00 4d 63 ee 49 83 fd 09 0f 87 12 04 00 00
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xec/0x630
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x12/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  <TASK>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  </IRQ>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7d/0x90
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  irq_exit_rcu+0xe/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __irq_exit_rcu+0x89/0xb0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x12b/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x316
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? clockevents_program_event+0xaa/0x120
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? lapic_next_event+0x20/0x30
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? native_x2apic_icr_read+0x20/0x20
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x46/0xc0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  __run_timers.part.0+0x1d6/0x280
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? dequeue_skb+0x510/0x510
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  call_timer_fn+0x2c/0x150
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  ? dequeue_skb+0x510/0x510
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  <IRQ>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Call Trace:
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CR2: 00007f162f172f5f CR3: 000000017a530000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8954befc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R13: ffff89362c94c41c R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: R10: 2065756575712074 R11: 696d736e61727420 R12: ffff89362c94c000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RBP: ffffb20000710e98 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: fffffffffffe09e8
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RDX: ffff8954befec6c0 RSI: ffff8954befe0580 RDI: 0000000000000300
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff89362c94c4c8 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb20000710e70 EFLAGS: 00010282
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Code: ff e9 31 ff ff ff 4c 89 e7 c6 05 f5 74 6c 01 01 e8 76 63 f9 ff 44 89 f1 4c 89 e6 48 c7 c7 20 dc cd 93 48 89 c2 e8 87 0e 1a 00 <0f> 0b e9 22 ff ff ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x20f/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./B550 Phantom Gaming 4, BIOS P2.10 08/02/2021
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: CPU: 23 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/23 Tainted: P           OE     5.17.5-76051705-generic #202204271406~1655476786~22.04~62dd706
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel:  videobuf2_common brcmutil cec snd_seq_device ecdh_generic ecc rc_core snd_timer videodev edac_mce_amd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea apple_mfi_fastcharge input_leds joydev mc rapl cfg80211 sysfillrect wmi_bmof snd sysimgblt k10temp soundcore mac_hid sc>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: Modules linked in: snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libcurve25519_generic libchacha ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel xt_nat veth tls nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_a>
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 23 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:529 dev_watchdog+0x20f/0x220
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp7s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
Jun 27 15:54:18 pop2204 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun 27 15:54:08 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5575a3cf7850] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:54:08 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5575bf92d300] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:54:08 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55758c7ca660] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5575a3cf6a50] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5575bf92cf10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55758c7ca660] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5575a3cf6a50] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5575bf92cf10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jun 27 15:53:56 pop2204 gnome-shell[2877]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55758c7ca660] is on because it needs an allocation.
```

I'm using PopOS/Ubuntu 22.04 5.17.5-76051705-generic #202204271406~1655476786~22.04~62dd706 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 17 16 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please send the full trace to LKML, if no one replies within 48 hours file a bug report here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform%20Specific%2FHardware under x86-64.

Comment: how to fetch the full trace? '__') @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: Your post stars with `---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---` which looks wrong. If that's all you've got in `dmesg`, OK, it just doesn't make sense to me.